# Remove background outside of Cardview corners

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have successfully implemented persistent bottom sheet in my application. I am using cardview with rounded corners but I want to get rid of unwanted background outside of cardview corners.

[image]

In this activity i am using recyclerview and bottomsheet. All is working fine but i want to remove white background outside corner.

[image: Remove red area]

**XML Code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Properties.PropertiesActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="55dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/TopLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:tint="@color/white"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Properties"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_properties"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TopLayout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/mcv_lineChart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_250sdp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.Card.Media"
        app:strokeColor="@color/light_gray"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="55dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_propertyGraph"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:tint="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Property Graph"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_propertyGraph" />

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                    android:id="@+id/lineChart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Themes.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AAAProperty" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/blue</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <!-- Spinner Divider -->
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Spinner -->
<style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_11ssp</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/light_gray</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.Card.Media" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">36dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">36dp</item>
</style>
```

I have searched a lot but could not find the solution. Kindly help me.

Comment: try to use a radius on the corners of the `MaterialCardView`, for instance `app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"`

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work cardCornerRadius makes all corners round thats why i used shapeAppearanceOverlay to make only top corners round

Comment: Can you share `ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.Card.Media`

Comment: @Zain I have updated the question. Kindly check

Comment: @Saify I do not believe the issue is that the background of the card is hiding the recyclerview contents. Rather, I think the problem is that the recyclerview is constrained to the top of the cardview, so it simply ends at the very top. You'll have to change it so that the recyclerview goes _behind_ the bottom sheet (and perhaps update the bottom padding of the recyclerview (with `clipToPadding="false"`) to make it possible for the user to scroll all the way).

Comment: Please check [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PtfVkdremMANwDhMMYYWAoRnN1a6Dm25/view) just added background colors so that you can check where is the white area comes from

Comment: @Zain thank you so much. The issue is resolved now.

Comment: @BenP. thank you so much. You are a genius. My issue is resolved.